# In Firestore, how can I prevent "Please ensure that the Firestore types you are using are from the same NPM package" errors

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have several NPM codebases that use Firestore. One is client-side, one is server-side, and I am trying to refactor some code to a common dependency codebase. The server codebase uses firebase-admin as its dependency, but if I try to set objects with sentinel types (e.g. firebase.firestore.Timestamp), I incur this error:

```
Please ensure that the Firestore types you are using are from the same NPM package
```

I can avoid mixing firestore implementations by injecting the instance into my library codebase, e.g.:

```
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";
const libraryCode = new MyFirestoreLibrary(admin.firestore())
```

But, are there ways to access these sentinel types in library code?

An example of what I'm hoping to make work is here: https://github.com/okhobb/firestore-dependency-tester

Comment: Quick question: you're only importanting firebase-admin as a dependency, correct? I believe that the latest versions of firebase-admin import the client version for most of it's types now, generally setting them as an alias, for example [admin.firestore.Timestamp](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.firestore.Timestamp). Or at least that's what I can read from [this issue from a year ago](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/issues/743), so it's possible that you ought to call the aliases, but I can't be sure without a [mre]. Would you kindly provide one?

Comment: Not correct (and maybe my assumption that this is possible is the issue). The shared common library only imports firebase (and not firebase-admin) as it is used both on the client and the server. The server library imports firebase-admin, firebase, and the shared common library. Is there a usage pattern where this sort of setup could possibly work? I have a simple example pair of codebases that demonstrate the issue. See: https://github.com/okhobb/firestore-dependency-tester

Comment: I just realized I spelled "importanting" instead of importing. That's embarassing. But yes, I'm afraid that to access the sentinel types without mixing firestore types you'd have to separate the code for the client and the admin, which would defeat the purpose of the library code you're wishing to establish; and to utilize both would lead to the error you're currently getting, or to an ambiguous resolution error (when in the admin side, most likely, as you've imported firebase and (not the admin) with the library). I would suggest type casting when using the library in admin,but it's ambiguous

Comment: Ok thanks. Is this in-scope for a feature request for the Firebase team? It seems like the cause is relying only on "instanceof" in https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-firestore/blob/c7d67fb749aaf76050c08d29b4c6fca28ec9f5ce/dev/src/serializer.ts to check for type compatibility. Later in that check a test for "isMomentJsType" doesn't use "instanceof" and thus would allow different versions of momentjs objects to mix. Could adding a "isFirestoreType" check work?

Comment: For a Feature Request? I do believe it would be, the request itself isn't anything out of this world, though it may go against the intended functionality. I do believe that implementing an "isFirestoreType" check could work, but I can't confirm it'll be done and it could lead to user errors and/or unintended exploits. Nevertheless I do encourage that you request it through [this link](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) because the Firebase team probably have a better idea as to how to implement this and it's viability than I do.

Answer (score 4):

I agree this is extremely silly from the firebase team. I'm in your exact sitiuation, and have shared code where I define types and objects between both client and server - sounds reasonable right?

Here's my workaround:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase-admin';
import Timestamp = firebase.firestore.Timestamp;


export const now = () => {
  const newTimestamp = Timestamp.fromMillis(Date.now()) as any;
  const ret =  JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(newTimestamp));


  for (const prop of Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Timestamp.prototype).filter(prop => prop !== "constructor"))
    ret[prop] = newTimestamp[prop]


  return ret as Timestamp;
}
```

This just creates a new object and copies the properties so that the toDate, toMillis etc functions are all still there, it's just not a direct instance of timestamp, so any instanceof checks will return false.

After doing that awful hack, it seems like the check they have in place to make sure "you are importing from the same npm package" no longer works.